# nls function in R how to deal with the selection of parameters

Tags: r, regression

I'm dealing with the adstock model and try to find the best alpha in the formula of adstock_t=ad_t+alpha*adstock_t-1. I found the following relevant code in R to solve this question:
[image]

Here, for the modeling, the guy used nls function, I have several questions about it:
first, it seems that the function sales~b0+bi*adstock is a linear function why we use the nonlinear fitting model nls here.
secondly, I'm wondering how the model choose the best b0,b1 and alpha(rate here). We only specify the start point of each parameter, how does the model go through all possible value and choose the best ones? Is there upper bound for the range of parameters? Does it choose the best parameters based on R square(minimize SSR)? But in our course, the instructor mentioned that we estimate the best rate using maximize likelihood, which makes me confused because the nls uses least square rule. Is that inconsistent?

Thanks for any help!

Jie

Comment: Regarding how `nls` does the fit: on the help page of nls you see that the argument `algorithm` allows you to set that, and the default is Gauss-Newton. For the statistical details, you better ask this on stats.stackexchange.com as your question is out of scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If `rate` were fixed then `sales` would be a linear function of `b0` and `b1` and we could solve it using `lm` but `rate` is not fixed.  It is true that `algorithm="plinear"` could be used in this case in which case only a starting value for the nonlinear parameter `rate` would have to be specified, starting values for linear parameters can be omitted with that algorithm.  Note that the formula required for `"plinear"` is not the same as for the other algorithms.  Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364402/r-nls-singular-gradient/18364669#18364669) of using `plinear` -- searching SO for `plinear` will find other examples.

`nls` does not try all possible values.  The method it uses is specified by the `algorithm=` argument and if nothing is specified it uses [Gauss-Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) by default.  It starts at some specified starting value and then moves a small amount downhill and repeats.  Exactly how that is done depends on the specific algorithm chosen. See `?nls` for details on the arguments and references.

### Note

When posting to SO do not use images but rather include a complete reproducible example including all inputs that others can copy and paste into their session to run.